# ActionBarDrawerToggle in the way of ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am trying to implement a custom `ActionBar` (containing a gradient) into my layout that supports the `NavigationDrawerFragment`. Having built a custom `ActionBar` layout in XML, I tested my app with the following result.

[image: Result of my custom ActionBar layout]

As you can see, the gradient does not start on the very right. It starts after the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` ("hamburger" menu button for `NavigationDrawerFragment`). **I'd like my gradient to run from the very left to the very right of the screen.**

So far, here is what I have:

```
private void showGlobalContextActionBar()
{
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setLogo(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View actionBarLayout = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);

    // Gradient
    final View gradientView = actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_gradient);
    PaintDrawable p = EricssonGradient.getActionBarGradient(gradientView);
    gradientView.setBackground(p);

    // Title
    titleView = (TextView) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.title);
    titleView.setTypeface(app.getFont());
    titleView.setText(res.getString(R.string.menu_title));

    // Profile icon
    ImageView profileIcon = (ImageView) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.icon_profile);
    profileIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if(app.isLoggedIn())
            {
                // Find and select the PROFILE fragment
                int profilePos = app.getFragmentPosition(ACDC.FRAGMENT_PROFILE);
                selectItem(profilePos);
            }
        }
    });

    //assign the view to the actionbar
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_gradient"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/horizontal_progress_bar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:layout_weight="4"/>

        <ImageView
            android:minWidth="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/icon_profile"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_profile"
            android:contentDescription="@string/action_profile"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#EFEDEE"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```